# XML parsing and DOM management in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I need to manage xml with java. Only DOM is enough...
I need something very simple or better I would really avoid to install new libraries...

what is the package to use in Java 6 ??

I looked in doc but nothing clear is provided, just a reference to xml in org but nothing good is provided... or I didn't find it :(

Thank you

Comment: You may write a simple helper class to accomplish your task around DOM. See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/8346867/851432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example. A complete tutorial can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/JavaTechandXML/#code14)

```
 public class ChessboardDOMPrinter {
 private DocumentBuilder builder;

 public void print(String fileName, PrintStream out)
   throws SAXException, IOException {
  Document document = builder.parse(fileName);
  NodeList nodes_i 
    = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodes_i.getLength(); i++) {
   Node node_i = nodes_i.item(i);
   if (node_i.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE
       && ((Element) node_i).getTagName()
          .equals("CHESSBOARD")) {
    Element chessboard = (Element) node_i;
    NodeList nodes_j = chessboard.getChildNodes();
    for (int j = 0; j < nodes_j.getLength(); j++) {
     Node node_j = nodes_j.item(j);
     if (node_j.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
      Element pieces = (Element) node_j;
      NodeList nodes_k = pieces.getChildNodes();
      for (int k = 0; k < nodes_k.getLength(); k++) {
       Node node_k = nodes_k.item(k);
       if (node_k.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
        Element piece = (Element) node_k;
        Element position 
          = (Element) piece.getChildNodes().item(0);
        out.println((pieces.getTagName()
                       .equals("WHITEPIECES")
                     ? "White " : "Black ")
                    + piece.getTagName().toLowerCase()
                    + ": "
                    + position.getAttribute("COLUMN")
                    + position.getAttribute("ROW"));
       }
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
  return;
 }
}
```

Comment: I can't think in something more useful than a good example. If you think that code doesn't help to write code, then you might be in the wrong place ;)

Comment: Well... it's right that uncommented code is not very useful but it depends by the case... :P in this case it helps me a lot gven that I needed just the name of the packages and some references, if you consider that I am en experienced programmer (not so much but a little, yes) those line are helpful :)

Comment: however... don't get hasty guys... nobody is in the wrong place.... we're all are here to help each other. Thanks everyone for you're help.

Answer (score 3):

XML DOM parser is included in Java 6. Here is a snippet for how to use it:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

....

final DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
final DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
final Document doc = docbuilder.parse( new InputSource( reader ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

The DOM API is in `org.w3c.dom`. To get started you'll need to use a `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`, which can be got from `javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory`.

All this is shipped with Java 6 by default.

Answer (score 0):

Use JAXB and parse XMl to bind to a DataObject. handling a dataObject is easy.
JAXB comes bundled with java 6 by default.

E.g.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("test.schema");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
```

Note - Good option if your XML format is fixed.